# Why do we take a limit in terms of a finite sum $\sum_{j=1}^M|x_j^m - a_j|^p \le \varepsilon$ before taking that $M$ to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I'm reading through some [notes](https://files.warwick.ac.uk/vgelfreykh/files/FA1_2010v2.pdf) on the convergence of $l^p$ spaces and at the bottom of page 20 the author first states the following:

For $M \ge 1$ and $m, n > N$:
$$\sum_{j=1}^M|x_j^m - x_j^n|^p \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j^m - x_j^n|^p < \varepsilon.$$

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we get
$$\sum_{j=1}^M|x_j^m - a_j|^p \le \varepsilon.$$

This holds for any $M$, so we can take the limit as $M \to \infty$:
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j^m - a_j|^p \le \varepsilon.$$

My question is: We had
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j^m - x_j^n|^p < \varepsilon,$$

right at the start so why didn't we just take $n \to \infty$ there? Why did we first take that limit in terms of a finite sum with $M$ terms, and then take $M$ to infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this would be "commuting the limits"

$\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j^m-x_j^n|\leq\epsilon$ means that $\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^M|x_j^m-x_j^n|\leq\epsilon$. Taking $n\to\infty$, we obtain
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^M|x_j^m-x_j^n|\leq\epsilon$$
this is, in principle, different from
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j^m-a_j|=\lim_{M\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^M|x_j^m-x_j^n|$$